# Do I still need concrete mounds under my shower if the floor is perfectly level (I poured self leveling cement)

Tags: shower

The manual shows these steps and I am not sure if they are still needed after pouring self leveling  cement

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the mounds provide better support for the edge of the cup ring as well as the inside.

Also, when the shower base is point loaded with 200lbs (or 220lbs plus 160lbs) it will deform slightly and the hardened mounds will maintain the support, prevent excessive bending that makes it feel cheap, and prevent "tapping" of the base to the floor, when load is applied and removed or shifted.

Apart from a firm  feel, preventing bending and deforming is important to maintain the water seal at the tile edge.

You can use the much cheaper sanded cement rather than floor levelling cement. The FLV will have to be mixed thicker/dryer than when used as a self leveler.

Comment: This is a high quality shower base, Kohler Ballast 60x32 heavy like hell and it doe not bend in any way when on the floorand you step on it. If it is just for that I would pass

Comment: @MiniMe You might be lucky and fully enjoy its longevity despite going against the manufacturer's recommendations. Sometimes those recommendations linger from other designs. Call them and ask.