# Fast set concrete or self leveling concrete for the mounds under the shower base?

Tags: cement, self-leveling-concrete

This is a follow up for this question
[Do I still need concrete mounds under my shower if the floor is perfectly level (I poured self leveling cement)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/228899/do-i-still-need-concrete-mounds-under-my-shower-if-the-floor-is-perfectly-level)

The manufacturer instructions say "mounds of floor leveling compound". Is this the self leveling cement or it is a different cement ?
Can't find anything like "floor leveling compound at Home Depot

Comment: Did the manufacturer say « fast set concrete »? But if you need the shower in use tomorrow then that is what I would go with. However, shower support kits are available with 5 adjustable screws in a frame which work well and don’t have a drying time!!

Comment: no that is just me speculating what mortar that could be. Can you please point me to the support kit you are talking about?> I can't find anything like that

Comment: https://www.hornbach.ch/shop/Pied-de-bac-de-douche-pour-bac-de-douche-acrylique-et-acier/7584278/article.html

Comment: how do you use that ? Install it under the shower base ? Mine sits on a concrete slab

Comment: Well I can’t see it working on top.

Comment: Your manufacturer appears to have a different opinion, but I've always understood plaster to be the preferred material - easily smooshed around, sets fairly quickly, doesn't shrink, is easy to remove with a sledgehammer when the next shower or tub is put in.

Comment: it will crack under pressure